# How to record each and every output value(numerical) within loop function and save it as .csv or .txt file?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to record all the EndToEnd values. Hvaing trouble doing this. Code keeps giving me the final value of the loop. I've been troubleshooting for a few days now. I feel like I'm overthinking the solution

```
while(D<n):
    print(D)
    print(F)
    G=((Basepairs*D)+(3*F)) 
    df = pd.read_table('01_03_2023trajectoryoutput.dat', delimiter=' ',     skiprows=range(0,G), nrows=1, header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 2])  
    df.head()

EndToEnd=(((A-X)**2+(B-Y)**2+(C-Z)**2)**(1/2)*(0.842))
print(EndToEnd)
```

I have tried `python oxDNA.py > End-to-End-DNA-Distance.txt` This did not work
I tried to import every value seperatly and python gave `NaN` error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clear and you are trying to perform mathematical task on a variable that is not a number. NaN = 'Not A Number'. You will need to do one of the following.

- Add code to first check if value can be converted into a number, if
  so then convert the cell value to an INT or some other numeric
  value. or check if it is empty and give a number for that.
  OR
- Convert the cell in the datasheet as a numeric value so when you read
  it will read in as a numeric value. This will also probably have to be checked to see if it is a numeric value as well.

IF it is numeric then perform your ENDTOEND calculation.

If not skip/modify/ensure it is a number.